# Toric Variety from a fan with "identical" edges

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry

I have this fan that I've been trying to construct a toric variety from. The problem is, it contains certain edges twice. These are the edges:

$$(1,0,1)$$
$$(0,1,1)$$
$$(-1,-1,1)$$
$$(0,0,1)$$
$$(0,0,1)$$

The last one appears "twice". Or at least that is what my calculation says. Without the double last entry, this would just be $\mathcal{O}(-3)$ over $\mathbb{CP}^2$.

I've been using the construction found in the Mirror Symmetry book by Hori et al. I have a matrix of charges $Q$

$$ Q^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & -3 & 0  \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -3 \end{pmatrix} $$

Then the Edges $\Sigma(1)$ of the fan $\Sigma$ are given by the kernel of this matrix $Q$ as

$$ \sum_{i=1}^5 Q_{ia} v_i = 0$$

And I get the above edges.

I'm specifically interested in the Divisor corresponding to this last entry. So, what happens when I have an edge twice? Or is this not allowed?

Comment: What does it even mean for an edge to "appear twice"? If I understand the Wikipedia article correctly, a "fan" is supposed to be a _set_ of cones rather than a multiset.

Comment: That is indeed my problem as well. It would seem that one edge would simply "disappear". But that seems rather strange. Or I've been calculating my fan wrongly. I will edit my question to include the construction process of my fan, perhaps the error lies there?